# Accessing non consecutive location memory by using SSE instructions

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

Hi,
I am trying to access the non consecutive memory location  and store the data at that location in C .It is working fine .
But when I am doing the same I am not able to get the proper output :
PFB -

Here is C Code:

```
unsigned char Src_data[8] = {251,193,214,254,232,192,208,191};
float temp[256] = {0.0};
float *out_data;
memset(out_data,0.0f,sizeof(temp));
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    unsigned char d= Src_data[i];
    out_data[d] = out_data[d] + 0.2;
}
```

Here is SSE CODE :

```
uchar *image_0 = Src_data;
__m128 scale_fact = _mm_set1_ps(0.2);
for(int i=0; i<8; i+=4)
{ 
    __m128i index= _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(image_0+i)));
    __m128 output   = _mm_loadu_ps(((out_data+index.m128i_u32[0])));
           output   = _mm_add_ps(output,scale_fact);
    _mm_storeu_ps((out_data+index.m128i_u32[0]),output);
}
```

During storing the output in SSE by using _mm_storeu_ps, consecutive memory locations are getting filled  instead of the index value .
Can anyone tell me how Can I fill particular index location of output .

Comment: This is generally referred to as "gathered" loads (and "scattered" stores), and is not supported in SSE. If your CPU is fairly new though then you can use AVX2, which does support gathered loads at least.

Comment: @Paul R,Can You tell me what is the instruction in AVX2 for doing the same ..so it will be easy for me to look for AVX2 coding

Comment: @Aswhin: sure - just go to the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) and type in "gather" - this will show you all the gathered load instructions/intrinsics, e.g. `_mm256_i32gather_ps`. Note however that there are no scattered stores, even in AVX2.